# SQL Query Statement Return Different Results

Tags: sql, sql-server

Newbie to the forum.  I am trying to write a MS SQL query that returns the number of unique user logons in the last 24 hours.  I am not a SQL expert.  Below are two queries that I have.  The 2nd one is and extension of the first where I want to group the result by date and hour.  My question is, the 2nd query return result larger than the first.  What am I missing?  Thanks\

### 1ST

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(RESOURCE_ID)) AS 'UniqueLogonUsers'
FROM live.AUDIT_LOG  WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE AUDIT_TYPE = 0  AND AUDIT_TIME >= DateAdd(hh, -24, GETDATE())
```

### 2ND

```
SELECT  CAST(AUDIT_TIME AS DATE) AS 'WhichDate',
        DATEPART(hh, AUDIT_TIME) AS 'WhichHour',
        COUNT(DISTINCT(RESOURCE_ID)) AS 'UniqueLogonUsers'
FROM live.AUDIT_LOG  WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE AUDIT_TYPE = 0  AND AUDIT_TIME >= DateAdd(hh, -24, GETDATE())
GROUP BY CAST(AUDIT_TIME AS DATE), DATEPART(hh, AUDIT_TIME)
ORDER By CAST(AUDIT_TIME AS DATE) DESC, DATEPART(hh, AUDIT_TIME) DESC
```

Comment: Users who login more than one hour in the past 24 hours are counted multiple times in the second query.

Comment: Improve your question or upvote the correct answer. You did ask why it returned different results and a user replied succinctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be because you are using GETDATE() which would have returned a different value each time?  Can you try putting a fixed date in there instead of GETDATE()?

Comment: Thanks but didn't fix it.

Comment: Understood it now.  You *don't* seem to have a problem, unless resource_id column is defined as a unique key.  The queries are behaving correctly.  When you do a "global" count distinct vs "scoped" count distinct (because of the group by), some of the resource_id's could be counted more than once.

Comment: Thanks.  So is there a way to remove those extra (duplicate) counts?

Comment: You can't, since the group by is involved.  You could probably write a subquery that first fetches rows with max AUDIT_TIME for a given RESOURCE_ID by doing a GROUP BY RESOURCE_ID and then do a second GROUP BY on that subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Your first query should only return 1 row - a count of logins in the last 24 hours. Your second breaks that count into rows for each Day/Hour combination, so thus will have more rows - one for each combination, with the counts of the logins during that hour.

Comment: Thanks.  Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: What's to fix? What's the intended output? put a sample in the question.